# Read whole Message from UDP Socket

Tags: sockets, unix, bsd, darwin

I'm sending data over an `UDP` socket and receive it in a loop with `read()`.
The input data looks like this:

```
String 1
String 2
String 3
....
```

I write data out with `send()`, each string after each other (in a loop).
How do I make sure that I can reconstruct the data on the receive end in the correct fashion (as I put the strings in)?

The received data can be split anywhere in the middle of the lines like so:

```
Packet 0: Stri
Packet 1: ng 1
Packet 2: String 2 St
Packet 3: ring 3
...
```

Do i have to introduce a custom `END OF MESSAGE` byte sequence to tell? Because `EOF` won't help here.

I need to be able to tell if a package is corrupted, and where the data blocks that belong together begin and end, as I sent them away beginning with `S` and ending with the `Number`! I can't use `TCP` because i need broadcast/multicast support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all messages to arrive, and in the same order they were sent, and to have an "end of message" indication, maybe TCP is better :-)

(TCP does this all out of the box.)